# Bootstrap Full page columns

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, height

I want to have two columns which fills up every time the full page size unattached from the given content.

The problem is that my solutions work until I began to scroll the page.

**Example**

```css
html,body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.left-content {
  background: red;
}

.right-content {
  background: green;
}

.container-fluid {
  height: 100%;
}

.row {
  height: 100%;
}

[class^="col-"] {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 left-content">
    LEFT COLUMN
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 right-content">
    RIGHT COLUMN
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Anyone have a solution for this problem?!

Answer (score 0):

How about adding col-xs-6 that accommodates extra small screens as well:

```css
html,body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
.left-content {
  background: red;
}

.right-content {
  background: green;
}

.container-fluid {
  height: 100%;
}

.row {
  height: 100%;
}

[class^="col-"] {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 left-content">
    LEFT COLUMN
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-6 right-content">
    RIGHT COLUMN
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is the following ... (Without scrollbars it works, http://img4host.net/upload/0300212156b139f10b24c.png) and (With scrollbars the background is not repeated anymore, http://img4host.net/upload/0300221156b13a232b0bd.png)